# check nth call in Sinon stubbed method

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon

Suppose I have a helper method `helper.someFn` and service method `servMethod` which calls `helper.someFn` multiple times. Now while testing `servMethod`, I stubbed `helper.someFn`.

```
// helper.js
exports.someFn = (param) => {
    return param + 1;
}


// service.spec.js
describe('Spec', () => {
    it('first test', (done) => {
        var someFnStub = sinon.stub(helper, 'someFn', (param) => {
            return 0;
        });
        // do servMethod call which calls someFn
        expect(someFnStub.firstCall.calledWith(5)).to.be.true;

        helper.someFn.restore();
        done();
    });
});
```

Lets say `servMethod` has called `helper.someFn` 5 times with different param each time. Inside test, I can access the first-call of `helper.someFn` with `someFnStub.firstCall`. I can access till third-call in this way. How can I access next calls like 4th or 5th calls?

Answer (score 8):

The source code shows that `firstCall`, `secondCall` and `thirdCall` are actually just sugar over `getCall`.

```
// lib/sinon/spy.js
    // ...
    this.firstCall = this.getCall(0);
    this.secondCall = this.getCall(1);
    this.thirdCall = this.getCall(2);
    this.lastCall = this.getCall(this.callCount - 1);
    // ...
```

So for asserting on the fourth call you would use `stub.getCall(3)`

Answer (score 6):

`stub.onFirstCall()` is short for `stub.onCall(0)`, `stub.onSecondCall()` is short for `stub.onCall(1)`, etc, so if you want to test the fourth call:

```
expect(someFnStub.onCall(3).calledWith(5)).to.be.true;
```

Documented here: http://sinonjs.org/releases/v3.2.1/stubs/#stub-onCall

Comment: Interestingly I just saw that I am using an old version of sinon ^1.17.7. And I found the doc for it in http://legacy.sinonjs.org/docs/

And in my case `onCall` did not work, rather `getCall` did work.

Comment: @RazinTanvir strange, as the docs state that `onCall` was added in 1.8 and you're using a later version.

Comment: OP wants to inspect arguments and result of nth call -- but the linked `onCall()` suggestion SPECIFIES what the result will be, per same linked docs:

`Defining stub behavior on consecutive calls [...] As of Sinon version 1.8, you can use the onCall method to make a stub respond differently on consecutive calls.`
Suggest `getCall()` instead, as indicated by @GeriTol: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57890296/250988
e.g., `var spyCall = spy.getCall(n); Returns the nth call.` -- https://sinonjs.org/releases/v9.0.2/spies

Comment: @DavidVMcKay you're correct, `onCall` is used to change runtime behaviour, whereas `getCall` can be called after the fact and is indeed that the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

`getCall(-nth)` where `nth` can be negative value.

This allows getting calls indexed from the end of the array:

```
spy.getCall(-1) // returns the last call
spy.getCall(-2) // the second to last call.
// ...
```

Docs: https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/spies/